# Issue with NSUserDefaults Class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, nsuserdefaults

I am following [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHMdThUQBJw) tutorial and at **09:42** He add  `NSUserDefaults` call this way :

[image]

But when I try to search this call I got Like this :

[image]

It is removed in **xcode_6.1_beta_2.1**?

When I try to written It :

```
var name = AnyObject?{
    get {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("name")
    }
    set{
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue!, forKey: "name")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
}
```

I am getting errors.

Like my First error is :

[image]

It it suggest to add code like this way so I did this :

```
    var name = AnyObject?{
    get {
        return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("name")
    }
    set{
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue!, forKey: "name")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
}()
```

But It happens again Like Delete `()` this and again Add `()` And continue at last line.

Any Solution for this issue?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `var name = AnyObject?` to `var name : AnyObject?`

[image]

Comment: I Added a screenshot from the actual tutorial showing the currect code :)